# can not find the stack on my aws account created with cloudformation

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

even though the terminal responded with the arn, it is unable to locate the stack that cloudformation produced.
I generated a stack and received a reply with the arn after configuring my account with the access key, secret key, region, and format, but when I checked the AWS account, it was not possible to discover the stack.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Some AWS products are regional or global. Depending on what you have deployed, you might have to check if you are in same region as your configuration.

On you top right hand side of the AWS console check if the region is the same as you used in your config.

Comment: Cloudformation like most (but not all) services is regional.   The region is also part of the ARN. So look at your arn and see what region it shows

Comment: it shows the region that i was specified in the configuration but can’t find the stack